# Is it possible in C# to have interface with fields of another interface but in the implementation use a class that implements an interface?

Tags: c#

The following is an example implementation.

But when I do it I get the following error 'Foo' does not implement interface member 'IBar.MyBar'.

```cs
public interface IBar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    public IBar MyBar { get; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Bar MyBar { get; }
}
```

Comment: What did the compiler say?

Comment: `public class Foo : IFoo {  public IBar MyBar { get; } }` should work. Your approach will only work in C# 9.0

Comment: Foo must implement IBar MyBar, not Bar MyBar...

Comment: Is `Bar` intended to be an interface or a class?

Comment: you need co-variant return-types, which is a proposal for C#9: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns

Comment: Anway it´s bit unclear why you need that. What do you expect `getMyFoo().MyBar` to return? Surely an `IBar`, no?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error is pretty clear: the interface `IFoo` indicates a member called a `MyBar` of type `IBar`, not `Bar`. This contract ensures that you allways know what you can expect from an API. So the following will allways return some kind of `IBar`:

```
IFoo foo = GetMyFoo();
IBar bar = foo.MyBar;
```

The implementation of your `Bar`-class is an internal detail, clients shouldn´t care for. So you can easily exchange that implementation without clients to re-compile.

There´s a [proposal for C#9](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns) to make return-types co-variant, though.

Comment: How could I do that with C# 9?

Answer (score 0):

So, after replicating the code, I think that you need to change the Foo class implementation.

As for now you have this:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Bar MyBar { get; }
}
```

And I think you meant to put it this way, which will work as you intend to:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
   public IBar MyBar { get; }
}
```

Note that in the IFoo Interface you implement MyBar as IBar and not as Bar, thus the error. If I'm missing something I am sorry, but I think that this is the problem.
Glad if I could help you! :)

Comment: No that's what I intended to do, because Bar implements IBar to use the implementation.